# Mysql Update Query IN phrase

Tags: mysql

Attention sql gurus,

How can I perform such a query?

```
UPDATE `qwiki`
SET haspix=1
where eword in (select distinct fmtag
                from qtagid)
```

It should basically set the 'haspix' flag to true for ewords found in another table.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. that's what it'll do. You could run it ,no?

Comment: Actually that one's not working, so I tried this one: UPDATE `qwiki` SET haspix=EXISTS(select fmtag from qtagid where fmtag=eword)
so far so good?!

Comment: It should work fine. How it is not working? Any errors? Post them please.

Comment: What is the error shown?

Comment: try to execute `select distinct fmtag from qtagid`?

Comment: I think it might be a bug in the mysql version I use because the first query did not work (just updated one single row) but the second one does.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem??? I even retry your query to confirm.

table a_test

```
    id  value    status  
------  -------  --------
     1  Hawaii   (NULL)  
     2  Hello    (NULL)  
     2  Test     (NULL)  
     3  What     (NULL)  
     4  World    (NULL)
```

table a_data

```
value   
--------
hello   
world
```

query

```
UPDATE a_test SET status=1 WHERE value IN (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM a_data)
```

result

```
    id  value    status  
------  -------  --------
     1  Hawaii   (NULL)  
     2  Hello    1       
     2  Test     (NULL)  
     3  ACH      (NULL)  
     4  World    1
```